# What is “X-Amzn-Trace-Id” in my Firefox request headers?

Tags: firefox, amazon-web-services, headers, brave, http-headers

I was browsing a website with domain [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org) that allows me to investigate my own HTTP request headers. This morning the website said they look like this:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6558b778-1cc87dac09df546a2a420a25"
  }
}
```

What sparked my interest is the field labelled `X-Amzn-Trace-Id`, which I have never seen before. So I tried to google what it is. I got the impression that it is related to Amazon, but it appears that all the articles that mention it already assume the reader knows what it is.

- But I don't know what it is. So I would like to know what some basic information about it: Who have come up with it? What is it supposed to be used for?
- If it assigns an id to my device, I'd like to get rid of it so I can optimize my anonymity. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is a header associated with an Amazon load balancer.

#### This does not track you personally, but it does track your browser, for strictly application load balancing needs.

A Google search [reveals this on Amazon’s AWS site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-request-tracing.html):

> When the load balancer receives a request from a client, it adds or updates the **X-Amzn-Trace-Id** header before sending the request to the target. Any services or applications between the load balancer and the target can also add or update this header.
>
> You can use request tracing to track HTTP requests from clients to targets or other services. If you enable access logs, the contents of the **X-Amzn-Trace-Id** header are logged.

So if you visited a site hosted by Amazon’s web services *and* that site used an application load balancer, this header would have been set by the server.

This is a functional header and not a header that reveals PII (Personally Identifiable Information) so I would not be concerned about privacy exposure and such.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Is it typically possible to unset or suppress headers in requests my browsers?

Comment: No. Your browser is not what's adding this header. It's the load balancer that's between you and the actual web server.

Comment: @MikkeMus Headers are set by servers or gateways; they are not set by your browsers. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: That's badly put. Headers are definitely set by the browser. However, (legitimate) intermediary parties may add, remove or modify headers freely, and there is no way to prevent this.

Comment: Which organization determines who is legitimate?

Comment: @MikkeMus There is no organization. What he means is as long as the HTTPS chain is complete and as long as software is not compromised, the headers are valid. A compromise would be something like a “man in the middle” attack. Which is rare.